Show that there are only finitely many pairs of positive integers $(n, m)$ such that $d(m!) = n!$.
Show that there are only finitely many pairs of positive integers $(n, m)$ such that $d(m!) = n!$, where $d(n)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of $n$.
My approach (it isn’t complete and probably not correct). Any help in writing a complete and correct proof :
To show that there are only finitely many pairs of positive integers $(n, m)$ such that $d(m!) = n!$, where $d(n)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of $n$, we need to compare the growth rates of $d(m!)$ and $n!$.
Understanding the Growth of $d(m!)$
The number of divisors of $m!$, denoted $d(m!)$, depends on the prime factorization of $m!$. If $m!$ is expressed as $p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$, where $p_i$ are primes and $e_i$ are their respective exponents, then:
The number of divisors $d(m!)$ is $(e_1 + 1)(e_2 + 1) \cdots (e_k + 1)$.
The exponents $e_i$ for each prime $p_i$ can be approximated as:
$e_i$ is roughly the sum of the integer divisions $\left\lfloor \frac{m}{p_i} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{m}{p_i^2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{m}{p_i^3} \right\rfloor + \cdots$.
For large $m$, the dominant term in this sum is approximately $\frac{m}{p_i}$.
Comparing Growth Rates
Let's approximate the growth rate of $d(m!)$:
The number of prime numbers less than or equal to $m$ is approximately $\frac{m}{\log m}$ by the Prime Number Theorem.
Each $e_i$ is roughly $\frac{m}{p_i}$, and the product $(e_1 + 1)(e_2 + 1) \cdots (e_k + 1)$ grows very rapidly.
Growth of $n!$:
Stirling's approximation for $n!$ provides a way to understand its growth:
$n!$ grows roughly as $\sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$.
Comparing $d(m!)$ and $n!$
To compare $d(m!)$ and $n!$:
$d(m!)$ grows super-exponentially with $m$, much faster than the factorial function $n!$ grows with $n$.
For large $m$, $d(m!)$ becomes significantly larger than any $n!$. This means that for sufficiently large $m$, there cannot be an $n$ such that $d(m!) = n!$.
Since $d(m!)$ grows much faster than $n!$ as $m$ and $n$ increase, there can only be finitely many pairs $(n, m)$ such that $d(m!) = n!$. Once $m$ reaches a certain threshold, $d(m!)$ will exceed $n!$ for all $n$, limiting the possible pairs to a finite set.

d(m!) doesnt grow faster than n! for the same reason d(x) doesnt grow faster than x. Also I don't think this comparison of growth rates is enough to provide a proof, as even if the growth rates of two functions is vastly different, as long they depend on different variables (n and m), they can be equal. Th growth rate argument only has weight when the functions depend on the same variable

@EnEm do you know how to approach it?

I think I got one approach now. The idea is to get a lower bound on m by comparing the exponent of 2 on the prime factorisation of each side. I' ll try to formalise it below in some time

@EnEm did you manage to write the proof?

Added an answer now

@math.enthusiast9 (You should "unaccept" the by EnEm for now, to make it clear that the question is not solved)

I would be surprised to see any solutions other than the trivial $(m,n)\in {(1,1),(2,2)}$.

@math.enthusiast9 what is the source of this question?

EDIT: realized a mistake in this answer, and its not correct anymore. Keeping it heree for other ideas to solve this.
Let $\varepsilon_p(x)$ denote the exponent of prime number $p$ in the prime factorization of x; and let $\pi(x)$ denote the number of prime numbers $\leq x$.
Let us consider the properties of the special pairs $(n, m)$ specified in the problem.
First we will find a lower bound of $n$ in relation to $m$, using the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $d(m!)$ and $n!$.
We know the exponent of $2$ in $n!$ 's prime factorization will be:
$$
\begin{split}
\varepsilon_2(n!) &= \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^1} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^2} \right\rfloor + \dots + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor}} \right\rfloor \\
&= \left( \frac{n}{2^1} - c_1 \right) + \left( \frac{n}{2^2} - c_2 \right) + \dots + \left( \frac{n}{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor}} - c_\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor \right), 
\quad \text{where } c_i = \frac{n}{2^i} - \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^i} \right\rfloor \in [0,1) \\
&= \left( \frac{n}{2^1} + \frac{n}{2^2} + \dots +  \frac{n}{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor}} \right) - \left(c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{n}{2^1} + \frac{n}{2^2} + \dots +  \frac{n}{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor}} +\frac{n}{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor}} -\frac{n}{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor}} \right) - \left(c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor \right) \\
&= \left( n -\frac{n}{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor}} \right) - \left(c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor \right) \\
&= \left(n - 1\right) - \left(c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor \right),
\end{split}
$$
which gives us $n-1-\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor <\,\varepsilon_2(n!)\,\leq n-1$.
For $d(m!)$, we have
$$d(m!) = \prod_{i=1}^{\pi(m)}\left( \varepsilon_{p_i}(m!) + 1\right),$$ so
$$
\begin{split}
\varepsilon_2\left(d(m!)\right) &\geq \text{count of i's where } \left( \varepsilon_{p_i}(m!) + 1\right) = 2 \\
&= \text{count of i's where }  \left( \left\lfloor \frac{m}{{p_i}^1} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{m}{{p_i}^2} \right\rfloor + \dots + \left\lfloor \frac{m}{{p_i}^{\left\lfloor \log_{p_i}m \right\rfloor}} \right\rfloor + 1\right) = 2 \\
&= \text{count of i's where } \left\lfloor \frac{m}{{p_i}^1} \right\rfloor = 1 \\
&= \text{count of i's where } \frac{m}{2} < p_i \leq m \\
&= \pi(m) - \pi\left(\frac{m}{2}\right).
\end{split}
$$
As $d(m!) = n! \,\Longrightarrow \varepsilon_2\left(d(m!)\right)$ must be equal to $\varepsilon_2(n!) \Longrightarrow \pi(m) - \pi\left(\frac{m}{2}\right) \leq n-1$.
Using some inequalities related to $\pi(x)$ from wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function
$$
\frac{x}{\log x} 
< \pi(x)
< 1.25506 \cdot \frac{x}{\log x}, \quad \text{for all }x \geq 17,
$$
we get
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{m}{\log m} - 1.25506\frac{m/2}{\log \frac{m}{2}} 
&\leq n-1 & \qquad \text{for all }m \geq 34 \\
\frac{m\left(2 \left( \log m - \log 2 \right) - 1.25506\log m\right)}{2\log m \left( \log m - \log 2 \right)}
&\leq n-1 \\
\frac{m\left(0.74494 \log m - 2\log 2 \right)}{2\log m \left( \log m - \log 2 \right)}+1
&\leq n
\end{split}
$$
This gives us a good enough lower bound on $n$ in relation to $m$. Finding an upper bound is simpler:
A trivial upper bound of $m$ is $m\geq n$ which can be proved trivially. However this doesn't help us a lot. A better upper bound can be found using the relation $2\cdot d(m!)\geq d((m+1)!)$ (from OEIS : https://oeis.org/A027423) which gives us $d(m!) \leq 2^{m-1} \Longrightarrow 2^{m-1} \geq n! \Longrightarrow m \geq 1 + \log_2(n!)$
Using these two inequalities, we can prove that there are finitely many pairs of $(n,m)$ which satisfy $d(m!)=n!$ if there exists a $N$ for which we cannot find a $m$ which satisfies both inequalities for all $n \geq N$

How did you calculate the sum in the first parentheses? \varepsilon_2(n!)&,=\left( \frac{n}{2^1} + \frac{n}{2^2} + \dots +  \frac{n}{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor}} \right) - \left(c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor \right) \
\varepsilon_2(n!)&,=\left(n - 1\right) - \left(c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_\left\lfloor \log_2n \right\rfloor \right)
\end{split} \end{multline}$

Edited a few extra steps in there now to explain it better. Ive used two things, first is: x + x + 2x + 4x + 8x ... 2^(n-1)x becomes 2^n x; and the second is to know the last term will always be 1

Could you also explain why that floor function equals to 1? \varepsilon_2\left(d(m!)\right) &\geq \text{count of i's where } \left\lfloor \frac{m}{{p_i}^1} \right\rfloor = 1 \

If you cloud explain how you got these inequalities using more details would be great cause I don’t really understand where you got them from: the inequalities for d(m!)

You can check why that floor equals 1 from the line above it. I am just checking the lower bound of exponent of 2, not the exact value here.

I got the second inequality for d(m!) directly from oeis, I don't know how we can prove that.  One thing to note here is this solution is not very novel, I am sure there are simpler solutions available

@EnEm Hey, I went ahead and edited your answer to improve the equation formatting and readability. Feel free to revert or edit if I made mistakes, but you can take a look at the code now for future inspiration (in particular I removed all your "multline"s and added double dollar signs for centralized equations)

@EnEm More importantly, $\left(\frac{1}{\log m} - \frac{1.25506}{2\log \frac{m}{2}}\right) \geq 0.1$ is wrong, since the expression approaches $0$ for large $x$. Maybe the argument can saved by a more careful analysis of the growth

@EnEm What we do have is $(\pi(m) - \pi(m/2))\sim \pi(m/2) \sim \frac{m/2}{\log(m/2)}$ as $m\to\infty$. Maybe you can go from here

Thanks for the editing, I browse from my phone so I can't be sure for the readibility for pc users. Also not sure how I missed that, my bad, I'll edit my answer to remove that mistake.

I realized I can't go from here, and the answer is no longer correct. Would probably have to think on some other lines to solve this
